# UnboundLocalError at /create-assignment/ATMser cannot access local variable 'context' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python, django

I have the blow view

```
def assign_item_view(request, pk):
    
    item = Item.objects.get(Serial_no=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AssignmentForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user')
    else:
        form = AssignmentForm(instance=item)

        context = {"item": item,"form": form} # move this line here
    return render(request, "workshop/Add_assignment.html", context)
```

`def assign_item_view(request, pk):

```
item = Item.objects.get(Serial_no=pk)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = AssignmentForm(request.POST, instance=item)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user')
else:
    form = AssignmentForm(instance=item)

    context = {"item": item,"form": form} # move this line here
return render(request, "workshop/Add_assignment.html", context)`
```

I got the below Erro

UnboundLocalError at /create-assignment/ATMser cannot access local variable 'context' where it is not associated with a value

Comment: if `request.method == "POST"` you don't set the `context` variable.

Answer (score 2):

The context should *not* only be used in case of a GET request:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect


def assign_item_view(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, Serial_no=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AssignmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-view-for-user')
    else:
        form = AssignmentForm(instance=item)
    context = {'item': item, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'workshop/Add_assignment.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.

---

> **Note**: You can make use of [**`redirect(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) and
> determine the url based on the view name and the parameters. This is more safe and elegant than performing string formatting and
> then wrap it in a [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect).

Comment: It doesnot save the data

Comment: @CHALCHISATAMIRU: well likely that means the form data was invalid (i.e. `form.is_valid()` returned `False`. By rendering `{{ form }}` in the template, you can see the errors.